# Rails 4 form for quantity placeholder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, placeholder

I'm trying to build an ecommerce store. I have a form for in the product/index.html.erb

It has Cart=>CartItems=>Products.

I'm wondering if I can use placeholders for individual numbers in the number_field. I've looked at the rails docs and I haven't found an answer to my question yet.

```
<%= form_for @cart_item, remote: true do |f| %>
   <div>
     <div class="input-group">
       <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1,max: 8 %>
       <div class="input-group-btn">
         <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id%>
         <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <%end%
```

So for example instead of 1 => the placeholder will say a weight and 2 and so forth till max 8.

The cart_items has a integer field for the quantity.

Comment: what do you mean by "So for example instead of 1 => the placeholder will say a weight and 2 and so forth till max 8."

Comment: Its hard to understand your question, could you provide more details?

Comment: So for example. In that line of code. I have a number_field for :quantity column in cart_item model. min number is 1, max number is 8. I want it to instead of saying one I want the placeholder to say "4oz". for the number 2 I want the placeholder to say "12oz" and etc etc. When they submit the form the cart_item will still be using quantity an integer. But to the user it's lists a placeholder weight.

Comment: Then you would have to change the min and max value, let's say instead of 1 it starts from 4, and next value is 8 then 12,16 and so on. Change the **step attribute** to 4 in the number field. Just after the text field add `oz` as text. When you get the values in backend divide it by 4 and store the value.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a select-box with the allowed options instead of a number box? Then you can use the exact labels (using oz and in amounts of four) that you'd like.

Comment: that's a good idea with the select-box